# Magento 2: how to send data by post method from a payment gateway?

Tags: payment-gateway, magento2

Magento 2: how to send data by post method from a payment gateway ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about a webhook from your payment gateway to your Magento2 setup so they notify you of an offline payment. I suggest you create an offline payment method. Then create a web-api endpoint that can process such information.

You need to give more information.

Comment: I just want to make payment gateway on magento 2 when a user click on our gateway option in magento 2 then will redirect to our gateway page with necessary data with post method. as of now i am stuck to post the data to our gateway provide suggestion or solutions.

Comment: I suggest you take Paypal module as a reference. That is the flow that happens when you select Paypal

Answer (score 0):

As per my research on Payflow pro magento 2.3.3 send data to payment gateway with following way.

```
vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/web/js/transparent.js

_postPaymentToGateway: function (data) {
    var tmpl,
        iframeSelector = '[data-container="' + this.options.gateway + '-transparent-iframe"]';
    tmpl = this.hiddenFormTmpl({
        data: {
            target: $(iframeSelector).attr('name'),
            action: this.options.cgiUrl,
            inputs: data
        }
    });
    $(tmpl).appendTo($(iframeSelector)).submit();
}
```

After success order with above function Post data to payment gateway.